How to do an 2d animated in unreal?
I am new to unreal and I dont know yet most basics, so I am doing an 2D game and I am focused in the main menu for now.
So resuming the background, when I was programming C# in .net, we could program what canvas behavior was, adding variables, drawings, user interactions etc, games, etc.
In my main menu, I have the title and buttons.
My main question is: Can you do programming animations in the canvas panel or in an widget blueprint? My point is just having some small aniamtions like a square going around the background of the menu, but I want them randomly spawned and not a premade animation, so I want to code those squares, paths, etc...
How do I do that? I used Image for background color, but I have not found a widget where I can actually program what I want in the background all 2D.
I know I can in the map set the camera and do a 3d animation too. The solution might be jsut set a camera and just do it in the map, but if there is a way to do it in the blueprint, could be owsome.

If your looking to learn the basics, best may be to start browsing the documentation Understanding the Basics

Its by any means helpfull, but I like to find out. Besides I have covered those basics already. But thank you for the input.

glad to help as much as anyone else here, but as you may know, questions get interaction with more helpful suggestions when they include details of an attempt at a solution to a specific problem. wish I could help more, I hope your question gets more helpful feedback.
